# Correct display of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

- How to display a string in correct format as i enter it in the textarea in ruby on rails?
- actually i enter some string in the textarea as:

  ***my name

  is jamal.***
- now there is a next line starting after *name*... but i get the following in the view...

  ***my name is jamal***
- which i don't want to be like that... so, how to get the correct format..?
- i hope u understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M002285) method

i.e. `<%= simple_format(params[:text]) %>` or `<%= simple_format(@text) %>` in your erb/rhtml view code

Comment: if it works for you please consider accepting the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're including the string within a textarea in the view then that is odd. However, if you are just printing the string to the page, then you will need to replace newline characters with "<br/>" tags.

Comment: how em i gonna do that... as i enter this in the textarea..?